# Understanding the proof of $A[[X]]$ is Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

The following proof is from Commutative ring theory by Matsumura:

[image]

Could someone give an explanation why the red underlined text is an ascending chain? It is not quite obvious to me.

Comment: Because if $m<n$ and $f\in I\cap X^mB$, then $X^{n-m}f\in I$ and $X^{n-m}f\in X^nB$, therefore all the "leading" coefficients of elements of $I\cap X^mB$ are leading coefficients of elements of $I\cap X^nB$.

Comment: Rant time: using $\subset$ when you mean $\subseteq$ is an abomination and should be stamped out (or at least called out) at any opportunity. The symbols $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ are clearly perfectly suited to reflect $<$ and $\leq$ (I don't know the history well enough to know whether this was intentional, but that matters little), so that's the only rational way to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I(0)$ is the ideal formed by all constant terms in all polynomials of $I\cap B\, ({}=I)$. The ideal $I(1)$ is formed from all the degree-1 coefficients of all elements in $I\cap XB$. Any element that appears as a generator of $I(0)$ according to this setup will also appear as a generator of $I(1)$. That's because if $a$ is the constant term of $f\in I\cap B$, then it is the first-degree coefficient of $Xf\in I\cap XB$. So moving from $I(0)$ to $I(1)$, you bring with you all the generators you had previously, and then potentially include a few more. This yields $I(0)\subseteq I(1)$.

An entirely analoguous argument holds in each degree.